# Gain loss in two-stage direct-coupled amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt, multisim

I am designing a direct-coupled two-stage amplifier with the following design constraints.

- V<sub>CE</sub> swings of both BJTs should be the same
- 2nd stage current (IC2) should be between 10 or 20 times the 1st stage current.

This is the schematic with the relevant symbols:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPBCfG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The specifications of the amplifier are as follows:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Vpp (output) | 5 V |
| Gain | 500 |
| Supply Voltage | 15 V |
| Load | 1 kΩ |

I have followed the following design procedure:

1. Derive the small signal model. I choose R5 to be 100 Ω. Using the small signal model and the gain equation which is A = R5 · h<sub>FE</sub>/R3 I obtained R3 to be 39 Ω (giving me a gain of 564 theoretically).
   [image: Small signal model used]
2. Choosing V<sub>CE</sub> of both stages to be 6 V to avoid signal clipping
3. Considering the AC load lines slope (~1/90 Ω), I set ICQ2 to be ~41 mA with R4 = 120 Ω. Now my VB2 is at 9.3 V.
4. Staying within the constraints for the second stage current, I choose R1 = 1.6 kΩ and R2 = 1 kΩ.
5. Then, on the biasing side of the input stage, by calculating VB1, I set Ra = 3.9 kΩ and Rb = 1.8 kΩ.
6. I randomly choose all the capacitors to be 1 μF.

Values used from the datasheets of the BJTs are:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| h<sub>FE</sub> (Q1 and Q2) | 220 |
| h<sub>FE</sub> (Q1 and Q2) | 120 |
| V<sub>BE</sub> (Q1) | 0.66 V |
| V<sub>BE</sub> (Q2) | 0.7 V |

To summarize the values I have chosen:

| Element | Value |
| --- | --- |
| R5 | 100 Ω |
| R3 | 39 Ω |
| R4 | 120 Ω |
| R1 | 1.6 kΩ |
| R2 | 1 kΩ |
| Ra | 3.9 kΩ |
| Rb | 1.8 kΩ |
| Caps | 2.2 μF |

When I simulate this setup in Multisim I don't get the expected output; I get a maximum gain of ~250.

[image: AC Sweep of Simulation]

**(Q1)** Why doesn't the calculated gain match the simulated gain?

**(Q2)** When this amplifier was physically implemented an even lower gain was obsereved. A decent gain close to the required amount was achieved only when R3 was set to 4.7 Ω, but that too quickly settles at a gain of 150 after a while. What causes this? Is it temperature effects or something else?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see Ic1 is around 4mA and Ic2 around 45mA.

Thus, \$r_{e1} = \frac{26mV}{4mA} = 6.5\Omega\$  and \$r_{e2} = \frac{26mV}{45mA} = 0.58\Omega\$

So the voltage gain of the first stage is around

$$A_{V1} = \frac{R_1||( h_{fe2}*r_{e2})}{r_{e1} + R_3||R2} \approx 2.5[V/V]$$

And the second stage gain will be around

$$A_{V2} = \frac{R_5||R_L}{r_{e2}} \approx  155 [V/V]$$

Therefore the overall gain will be around 2.5*155 = 380V/V  for Q2 hfe equal 220. But if Q2 hfe is 120, then the gain will drop to about 1.45 * 155 = 224 V/V.
The first stage gain is now around 1.45[V/V].

Also, you need to increase the values of the capacitors. Especially the C2 and C3 values.

C2 = 0.16/(6.5Ω * 20Hz) = 1200µF and C3 = 0.16/(0.58Ω * 20Hz) = 13000µF.

Comment: Could you  explain why you equate the capacitor impedence with the emitter resistance to find the capacitor values? TIA

Comment: The emitter capacitors form a RC high-pass together with the transistor's emitter output resistance. At the cross-over frequency of a passive RC element, the (imaginary) impedance of the capacitor has the same magnitude as the resistor's (real) resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Old op schematics ...

> I get a maximum gain of ~250

Here is a simulation with your values (except Q2 BJT model, R4 and R3).

I only get a gain of ~ 160 ...

[image]

With OP corrected schematic ... Capacitors changed for wide bandwidth.

[image]